# Create a global (not user specific) executable configuration in Xcode

Tags: xcode, configuration

Xcode normally saves its executable configurations in the user specific ".pbxuser" file. Is there a way to tell Xcode to save these configurations globally, in the "project.pbxproj" file, so all users can use them?
Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your .pbxuser file to default.pbxuser and then whatever defaults are stored in there (including executable configurations) can be shared with other users.  If they change settings then that will be reflected in their user.pbxuser file.